# Reactive kafka stream example with spring boot webflux

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to build a Spring Boot WebFlux application which consume events from one Kafka topic does some processing(would involve operation of reactive db lookup) on it and send them to another kafka topic. Currently the application uses webflux and spring cloud data streams for kafka.

Can some please suggest is it fine to use Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Stream API or should I use something else to achieve end to end reactive behaviour.

Tried with Spring boot WebFlux, spring cloud data stream kafka streams.

Processor example here

[image]

Comment: Hi @anusheel chandra. Have you tried https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/ ?

Comment: Please do not attach images for code. You can use the editor to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like you are using the Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams binder, but you mention `Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Stream API` . I assume you are using the regular Kafka binder in Spring Cloud Stream based on message channels since nothing in the code you provided points to any Kafka Streams API. Assuming this is the case, the best way to achieve full end-to-end reactive behavior is to use the new reactive Kafka binder (not yet released, but part of the `4.0.0` release, which is presently in the RC stage). More details on this reactive Kafka binder is available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_reactive_kafka_binder). This binder implementation is based on the reactor Kafka project from Project Reactor. The regular message channel-based Kafka binder is not based on reactive models and could block when consuming/producing. Therefore, if you are looking for an end-to-end reactive paradigm, use the reactive Kafka binder.

Comment: Hi @sobychacko

I am using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-stream with spring cloud function.

My setup is based upon the below example:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/1e4a4f3239126d31638b408f665846272bf07abc/multi-binder-samples/multi-binder-two-kafka-clusters

The only thing i have changed from the sample is to add flux to the Processor and build a webflux api around it,

Thanks

Comment: Even in that case, your `Function<Flux, Flux>` could benefit from `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-reactive`.

Comment: Thanks @sobychacko I will do that. Do you know the tentative date of the above mentioned RC becoming a productive version .

thanks

Comment: Dec 14th (2022) is when spring-cloud `2022.0.0` is slated for the GA release.

Comment: Hi @Sobychacko

Just a follow up about the reactive binder as mentioned above, do we also have the reactive binder for kafka streams ? Or i can use spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-reactive for streams too.

Thanks

Comment: There is no reactive binder for Kafka Streams. In Kafka Streams, there is no micro-batching; instead, it works on a single record basis. Kafka Streams handles things like back-pressure, message throttling, etc., behind the scenes. Basically, reactive constructs are not a good match for Kafka Streams, and therefore, we do not provide a binder that wraps Kafka Streams with reactive.

Comment: @sobychacko, so what is the proper way to use Kafka Streams in reactive paradigm? So to say I have the service built in WebFlux and I do really need Kafka Streams functionality?